# Converting from VBA to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm trying to convert this little code from Vba to Vb.net without success.
Would like some help please.

```
Dim str As String, i As Long

For i = 0 To lstPages.ListCount - 1

    If lstPages.Selected(i) Then
        If str <> vbNullString Then str = str & "-"
        str = str & lstPages.List(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you tried?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > So you want the third column, from all selected rows of the ListView, in one string separated by "-"?
> >
> > Yes that's right.

Then do:

```
    Dim values As New List(Of String)
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lstPages.SelectedItems
        values.Add(lvi.SubItems(2).Text)
    Next
    Dim str As String = String.Join("-", values)
    Debug.Print(str)
```

Comment: Hi. Your code works well. But i wasn't very clear.
The "lstPages" is a ListView with 3 collumns and i need to get the 3 collumn to the string

Comment: And then just mash all the rows together?...

Comment: I need to get the third column value to the string

Comment: So you want the third column, from all selected rows of the ListView, in one string separated by "-"?

Comment: Yes that's right. I was trying something like this:

If lstPages.SelectedIndices(i) Then
      If str <> vbNullString Then
         str = str & "-"
      End If
   str = str & lstPages.FocusedItem.SubItems(i).Text
End If

But i get an error "Argument no specified"
Sorry, real amateur here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do something like this:

```
For i as integer = 0 To lstPages.ListCount - 1
If lstPages.Selected(i) Then
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then 
     str &= "-"
    str &= lstPages.List(i)
End If
Next
```

Comment: He's converting to VB.Net.  The .Net ListBox doesn't have `.ListCount`, `.Selected`, or `.List` like old VB6 one did...